# How to multiply two hex numbers using memory manipulation?

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm in the process of reading "Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software" by Charles Petzold, and I got to page 228 of the book where it is explained how a multiplication of 2 hex numbers ( 00A7h (167 in decimal) times 001Ch (28 in decimal) ) is done in memory. 
   I need to mention I am the start of learning of how a CPU works, so please don't be too harsh to me if I get things wrong.

Please, first take a look at the contents of page 228 that I have cited at the bottom of the post.

I have these two issues:

1. Why is the carry equal to 1 after the six instructions have been executed for the first time, since the addition of 00h ( address 1005h ) + A7h ( address 1001h ) results in no carry?
   Is it 1 because once "Add with carry byte" (22h) opcode is being used adds 1 regardless if there is a resulting or not resulting carry from a low-order byte addition?
   I know A7h has to be added to itself for 28 times to get the right result, and I see that is supposed to be achieved by incrementing the value of 1004h.

```
        - -
1000h: |00h| <- High-order byte
        - -
       |A7h| <- Low-order byte
        - -
1002h: |00h| <- High-order byte
        - -  
       |1Ch| <- Low-order byte
        - -
1004h: |00h| <- High-order byte
        - -  
       |00h| <- Low-order byte
```

```
                 ----------------------
                | + carry  |  0  |  1  |
                |----------|-----|-----|
                |    0     |  0  |  0  |
                |----------|-----|-----|
                |    1     |  0  |  1  |
                 ----------------------


                 ----------------------
                | + sum    |  0  |  1  |
                |----------|-----|-----|
                |    0     |  0  |  1  |
                |----------|-----|-----|
                |    1     |  1  |  0  |
                 ----------------------
```

2. What I can't also wrap my head around is how is A7h still being kept in memory at address 1005h after the six instructions have been executed for the second time and why isn't 1004h's value 01h, but it is 02h instead?
   Shouldn't there be 14E, as a result of previously stored A7h at address 1005h (from the first time the 6 six instructions have been executed) added with A7h at address 1000h? But then, that couldn't be possible since 14E is two bytes, and obviously two bytes can't fit into one byte.

These are the operation codes that are being used:

```
            |---------------------|---|
            |Load                 |10h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Store                |11h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Add                  |20h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Subtract             |21h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Add with Carry       |22h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Subtract with Borrow |23h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Jump                 |30h|
            |---------------------|---|
            |Halt                 |FFh|
            |---------------------|---|
```

That's what I see after the first execution of the six instructions, according to my understanding:

```
        - -
1000h: |00h| 
        - -
       |A7h|
        - -
1002h: |00h| 
        - -
       |1Ch|
        - -
1004h: |01h| <- Why?
        - -
       |A7h| 
        - -
```

That's what I see after the second execution:

```
        - -
1000h: |00h| 
        - -
       |A7h|
        - -
1002h: |00h| 
        - -
       |1Ch|
        - -
1004h: |02h| <- Why 02h and not 01h, since 1005h is still A7h?
        - -
       |A7h| <- Shouldn't there be 14E!? Hmm, It can't be. What am I missing? 
        - -
```

In the contents of page 228 listed below I noticed this:

```
        - -
0012h: |30h| Jump to the instruction at 0000h
        - -
       |00h|
        - -
       |00h|
        - -
```

Wouldn't it make more sense if the jump would occur at address 1009h? Because that way I can see why 1005h stays the same and only 1004h changes, in the case I am right about how "Adding with carry" works?

If the information I'm providing is not enough for you to help me, please let me know.

### **~Page 228~**

***Obviously, we must ensure that the Set It signal is 1 only if the instruction
code is 30h and the address has been latched.
The Jump instruction is certainly useful. But it’s not nearly as useful as
an instruction that jumps sometimes but not all the time. Such an instruction is known as a conditional jump, and perhaps the best way to show how
useful such an instruction can be is to pose a question: How can we persuade
our automated adder to multiply two 8-bit numbers? For example, how do
we get the result for something as simple as A7h times 1Ch?
Easy, right? The result of multiplying two 8-bit values is a 16-bit product. For convenience, all three numbers involved in the multiplication are
expressed as 16-bit values. The first job is to decide where you want to put
the numbers and the product:***

```
        - -
1000h: |00h| 16-bit multiplier
        - -
       |A7h|
        - -
1002h: |00h| 16-bit multiplicand
        - -
       |1Ch|
        - -
1004h: |00h| <- 16-bit product goes here
        - -
       |00h| <- and here
        - -
```

***Everyone knows that multiplying A7h and 1Ch (which is 28 in decimal)
is the same as 28 additions of A7h. So the 16-bit location at addresses 1004h
and 1005h will actually be an accumulated summation. Here’s the code for
adding A7h to that location once:***

```
        - -
0000h: |10h| Load byte at 1005h into accumulator
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |05h|
        - -
0003h: |20h| Add byte at 1001h to accumulator
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |01h|
        - -
0006h: |11h| Store contents of accumulator at 1005h
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |05h|
        - -
0009h: |10h| Load byte at 1004h into accumulator
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |04h|
        - -
000Ch: |22h| Add with Carry byte at 1000h to accumulator
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |00h|
        - -
000Fh: |11h| Store contents of accumulator at 1004h
        - -
       |10h|
        - -
       |04h|
        - -
0012h: | : |
        - -
```

***At the completion of these six instructions, the 16-bit value at memory
locations 1004h and 1005h will equal A7h times 1. Therefore, these six
instructions have to be repeated 27 more times in order for that 16-bit value
to equal A7h times 1Ch. You can achieve this by typing in these six instructions 27 more times beginning at address 0012h. Or you can put a
Halt instruction at 0012h and press the Reset button 28 times to get the final
answer.
Of course, neither of these two options is ideal. They both require that
you do something—type in a bunch of instructions or press the Reset button—a number of times that’s proportional to one of the numbers being
multiplied. Surely you wouldn’t want to generalize this process for 16-bit
values that you want to multiply.
But what if you put a Jump instruction at 0012h? This instruction causes
the counter to start from 0000h again:***

```
        - -
0012h: |30h| Jump to the instruction at 0000h
        - -
       |00h|
        - -
       |00h|
        - -
```

***This certainly does the trick (sort of). The first time through, the 16-bit value
at memory locations 1004h and 1005h will equal A7h times 1. Then the
Jump instruction will go back up to the top. At the end of the second time
through, the 16-bit result will equal A7h times 2. Eventually, it will equal A7h
times 1Ch, but there’s no stopping it. It just keeps going and going and going.***

Comment: Where does it claim that carry is 1, or that 1004h will be 1? I can only see _"the 16-bit value at memory locations 1004h and 1005h will equal A7h times 1"_ which means `00h A7h`.

Comment: After the first execution of the six instructions, the memory at 1004 is `0x00 0xA7`. After the second execution, it's `0x01 0x4e`.

Comment: Ah, right. I see how it works now. Thank you both for helping me out!